# Duplicate html tags ruin parts of WP site

Tags: html, wordpress, tags, duplicates

I'm at a loss with this error, on some parts of my WP site I'm getting duplicate html tags added automatically on saving changes.

On visual editing, after publishing I get these added to my post:

```
     &amp;lt;br /&amp;gt; &amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;
```

Since it's visual, I can see these tags all over my newly published pages, meaning I have to go back and manually remove these lines and update the post so it looks as intended.

On some plugins I can't add multimedia content because they are automatically replaced by br tags. Doesn't matter if I add media in text or visual, upon updating they automatically disappear.

But the most infuriating is that I can't log out anymore, because the logout URL should look like this:

```
     http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=...
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
     http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;_wpnonce=...
```

So "&" becomes "& amp;" which breakes logout.

What I've tried:
Disabling all plugins, resetting plugins folder, deleting all unused plugins, switching back to base theme, disabling global java scripts (I have popups on the site which needs it).

I can't exactly tell when did it go wrong, it could have been a WP-update or something like that but I can't trace back the error and it doesn't seem like any other users experience the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, it was quite easy.
I needed to edit wp-config.php and disable custom_tags:

```
 define('CUSTOM_TAGS', false );
```

I do not know what set it to true, maybe it was a plugin I briefly installed and then deleted, but it messed up the site quite badly.

Every problem I mentioned above got solved immediately once I set it to false.